# Tailwindcss grid issue start/end

Tags: tailwind-css

I can't see where I am going wrong in this code and it's driving me crazy.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 my-10">
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">a</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">b</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">c</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">d</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">e</div>
  <div class="col-start-1 col-end-6">long</div> 
</div>
```

I was expecting to see something like the below:

```
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|
|             long            |
|=============================|
```

Instead I am seeing:

```
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|
| long|
|=====|
```

What makes it even weirder is if I use this it works as indented (I have only added 1 extra column):

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4 my-10">
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">a</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">b</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">c</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">d</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">e</div>
  <div class="bg-secondary p-2 rounded-xl w-full my-2">f</div>
  <div class="col-start-1 col-end-7">long</div> 
</div>
```

Now for the insane part. If I take the original 5 col layout and just make the end 7 rather than 6 it works but slightly pushes the column every so slightly, almost like this:

```
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |
|=====|=====|=====|=====|=====|=|
|             long              |
|===============================|
```

I figure I have to be missing something or just cant see something, but I'm just losing my mind at the moment.

Comment: Your code is look fine, are you using compilers like postcss ?

Comment: It's working fine, here is the live working example of above code
https://play.tailwindcss.com/KvfQOyZPxb